# Collection Prototype and Doctrine Persistance ManyToOne Relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Context : I am building my little TodoList bundle (which is a good exercice to go deep progressively with Symfony2), the difficulty comes with recursivity : each Task can has children and parent, so I used Gedmo Tree.
I have a collection of tasks each having a sub collection of children, children collection has prototype enabled so I can display a new sub task form when clicking "add sub task".
I wanted the default name of the subtask to be "New Sub Task" instead of "New Task" set in Task constructor, so I figured out how to pass a custom instance for the prototype and took some care for preventing infinite loop.
So I am almost done and my new task is added with the name I set when saving...

Problem : I am not able to persist the parent task to the new sub task, the new task persist the name well, but not the parentId, I probably forgot somewhere with Doctrine, here is some relevant parts :

// Entity Task

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="task")
 */
class Task {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Name must be not empty")
     */
    protected $name = 'New Task';

     //....

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(name="rgt", type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(name="root", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $parent = null;// 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $parentId = null;


    /**
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"status" = "ASC", "created" = "DESC"})
     */
    private $children;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }


   /**
     * Set parentId
     *
     * @param integer $parentId
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setParentId($parentId){
        $this->parentId = $parentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parentId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getParentId(){
        return $this->parentId;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $parent
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setParent(\Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $parent = null){
        $this->parent = $parent;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task 
     */
    public function getParent(){
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param \Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $child
     * @return Task
     */
    public function addChild(\Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $child){
        $this->children[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $child){
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }
}
```

// TaskType

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, ['label' => false])
            ->add('notes', null, ['label' => 'Notes'])
            ->add('status', 'hidden')
            ->add('parentId', 'hidden')
            ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($builder){
            $record = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if(!$record || $record->getId() === null){// if prototype
                $form->add('minutesEstimated', null, ['label' => 'Durée', 'attr'=>['title'=>'Durée estimée en minutes']]);
            }elseif($record && ($children = $record->getChildren())) {
                // this is where I am able to customize the prototype default values
                $protoTask = new Task();
                $protoTask->setName('New Sub Task');
                // here I am loosely trying to set the parentId I want
                // so the prototype form input has the right value
                // BUT it goes aways when INSERT in mysql, the value is NULL
                $protoTask->setParentId($record->getId());

                $form->add('sub', 'collection', [// warn don't name the field 'children' or it will conflict
                    'property_path' => 'children',
                    'type' => new TaskType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    // this option comes from a form type extension
                    // allowing customizing prototype default values
                    // extension code : https://gist.github.com/jumika/e2f0a5b3d4faf277307a
                    'prototype_data' => $protoTask
                ]);
            }
        });
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task',
            'label' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent(){    return 'form';}
}
```

// my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template("DmidzTodoBundle:Task:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    $this->request = $request;

    $repo = $this->doctrine->getRepository('DmidzTodoBundle:Task');
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

    //__ list of root tasks (parent null)
    $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select(['p','FIELD(p.status, :progress, :wait, :done) AS HIDDEN field'])
        ->addOrderBy('field','ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('p.id','DESC')
        ->andWhere('p.parent IS NULL')
        ->setParameters([
            'progress' => Task::STATUS_PROGRESS,
            'wait' => Task::STATUS_WAIT,
            'done' => Task::STATUS_DONE
        ])
        ->setMaxResults(20)
        ->getQuery();

    $tasks = $query->getResult();

    //__ form building : collection of tasks
    $formList = $this->formFactory->createNamed('list_task', 'form', [
            'records' => $tasks
        ])
        ->add('records', 'collection', [
            'type'=>new TaskType(),
            'label'=>false,
            'required'=>false,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ])
        ;

    //__ form submission
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $formList->handleRequest($request);
        if($formList->isValid()){
            // persist tasks
            // I thought persisting root tasks will persist their children relation
            foreach($tasks as $task){
                $em->persist($task);
            }
            $em->flush();
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('dmidz_todo_task_index'));
        }
    }

    return [
        'formList' => $formList->createView(),
    ];
}
```

As mentionned in the comments in TaskType, the form prototype of the new sub task has the right value for parentId which is posted, BUT the value is gone and NULL on INSERT in db (looking at the doctrine log).
So do you think it is the right way of doing, and then what thing I forgot for persisting correctly the parent task of the new sub task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your child setting you should set the parent when adding, like so..

```
/**
 * Add children
 *
 * @param \Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $children
 * @return Task
 */
public function addChild(\Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $children){
    $this->children->add($children);
    $children->setParent($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove children
 *
 * @param \Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $children
 */
public function removeChild(\Dmidz\TodoBundle\Entity\Task $children){
    $this->children->removeElement($children);
    $children->setParent(null);
}
```

When your prototype adds and deletes a row it calls `addChild` and `removeChild` but it doesn't call the `setParent` in the associated child.

This way any child that is added or removed/deleted get automatically set in the process.

Also you could change the `$children` to `$child` as it makes grammatical sense and it's really bugging me because I am a child(ren).

Comment: thank you man it works, you made my day :) I was missing this *little* piece of relation, I red few docs but wasn't able to apply correctly to this case...I understand better now you tell me addChild and removeChild are called in the collection prototype process. Yes you are totally right, I have to change this typo also, it is confusing, there is no need more ;) you desserve some points, thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird to me that you try using the `parentId` field as a simple column, whereas it is a relation column. Theoretically, you should not:

```
$task->getParentId(); //fetching a DB column's value
```

but instead:

```
$task->getParent()->getId(); //walking through relations to find an object's attribute
```

However, if you really need this feature to avoid loading the full parent object and just get its ID, your `setParentId` method should be transparent (although, as mentionned, I'm not sure using the same DB field is valid):

```
public function setParent(Task $t = null) {
    $this->parent = $t;
    $this->parentId = null === $t ? null : $t->getId();
    return $this;
}
```

Back to your issue: in the `TaskType` class, you should call:

```
$protoTask->setParent($record);
```

instead of:

```
$protoTask->setParentId($record->getId());
```

The reason:

- you tell Doctrine `parentId` is a relation field (in the `$parent` attribute declaration), therefore Doctrine expects an object of the proper type
- you also tell Doctrine to map this relation field directly to an attribute (the `$parentId` attribute declaration), I'm neither convinced this is valid, nor convinced this is good practice, but I guess you did some research before going for this structure
- you set `$parentId`, but `$parent` has not been set (i.e. `null`), so Doctrine must erase the `$parentId` value with the `$parent` value: your code is proof that Doctrine handles attributes first, *then* computes relations ;)

Keep in mind Doctrine is an *Object Relational Mapper*, not a simple query helper: *mapper* is what it does (mapping persistence layer with your code), *relational* is how it does it (one-to-many and the like), *object* is what it does it on (therefore not directly using IDs).

Hope this helps!

Comment: well I used Gedmo Tree annotations and followed a few docs for doing like this, but I am fairly new with Symfony  and Doctrine. I tried $protoTask->setParent($record); already and the relation still not being saved. I am wondering if it is the good place to set the relation (in form type buildForm method), it may be in controller ? that is this type of precision I need...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$task->getParent()->getId()` will not trigger a request to the database as the proxy object already 'knows' its identifier.

Comment: In fact I used input parentId for desesperately assigning it and pray the relation would be saved with...

Comment: @dmidz Wherever you set the relation, the entities are still and always managed by Doctrine's Entity Manager, so setting a relation is just a design question, not a technical limitation.
If setting the parent (as an object I mean, contrary to setting the parent's ID) does not work, either this double `parentId` declaration drives Doctrine mad (though it would have raised some exception/error I suppose), or, more probably, `setParent` is called with `null`. Maybe triggering an exception (or dumping the call stack and dying) when `null` is passed to setParent would give you more information?

Comment: yes parent is maybe passed null somewhere, I give a try...anyway if I change the parentId input value of a sibbling subtask already existing in db, of course it works, the only difference is the subtask exists already...I feel this is not the right place to set relation but I am not enought experimented

Comment: Aww, I hadn't spotted that earlier, but in your controller, the tasks you persist are already existing in your DB (as you retrieve them from a query). The tasks you need to persist are the ones created by your form, i.e. the 'sub'-named tasks. So I wonder how it is you managed to insert rows based on this code, as it shouldn't insert anything :/

Comment: yeahhh I think it's more coming from that, the fact IS everything was saved, even subtask add, but not the relation...thank you for pointing that...so I need to loop over form->getData() or something like that ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with forms but it is probably something like that. You need to retrieve the objects that were created by the form (i.e. the end-user), which are defined by your `$form->add('sub', 'collection'...` (so you should be able to retrieve `Task` instances somehow)

Comment: ok what is working is to loop over $formList->get('records')->getData(); then loop over task->getChildren(), then applying manually $children->setParent($task); no need to call each persist, only flush after loops...then the relation is saved correctly...and finally setting parent in buildForm is totally useless...so I need to loop recursively to set manually parent of tasks (based on the form data structure posted) in CONTROLLER which is what I was worried about...thank you...can go further now...

Comment: Explicitly setting the parent for "children" seems flawed (how could they be children of an entity and can't tell who their parent is?). Theoretically, you should 1/ keep the parent setting in the form, 2/ loop over `$formList->get('sub')` (I guess that's the call) in order to just persist these elements. Anyway, now you have a working solution to fall back to, still it seems weird! :)

Comment: typo : $child->setParent($task); yes it seems weird but that is...entity builded from posted data knows its children (and the new one added) but the relation is not propagatting...nor setting the right parentId (or parent object) in buildForm prototype and posting it doesn't work...maybe a Symfony2 and Doctrine specialist could explain, probably an "owner" relation subtile. Precisions : I am using Symfony 2.5 but specifically doctrine/orm 2.4.2